# Configuring Sonar / Grails

Tags: grails, sonarqube, codenarc

I am using Sonar in my Grails project. My configuration is in a sonar-project.properties file:

```
sonar.projectKey=com.mastercard.labs.cplatform
sonar.projectName=Commerce Platform
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.sources=src/groovy,grails-app/services,grails-app/domain
sonar.language=grvy
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

I want to adjust the rules for codenarc.  I usually do this in my BuildConfig.groovy.

```
codenarc.properties = {
    GrailsPublicControllerMethod.enabled = false
    GrailsDomainHasToString.enabled = false
    GrailsDomainHasEquals.enabled = false
    GrailsStatelessService.addToIgnoreFieldNames = 'grailsApplication'
}
```

And when I run codenarc locally, it's all cool and puts up the config.  But sonar doesn't.

How do I make sonar pick up these rules?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible @Burt, the only way to tune the rules to be used is by updating your SonarQube quality profile.